# use distribution server for signalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-2

I use signalR for connect client to server,how can I use multi server for signalR connection,for example a signal connection shared between 3 or 4 server,where all user connect to one endpoint but multi server in backend running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for what SignalR refers to as a backplane for scaling out.

Start with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr). Then go from there.